# Why data inside database is deleting after running ebean.mysqldatabase.ddl.run=true?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, ebean

I'm making project using SpringBoot and Ebean orm with MySql Database. I have created few tables in database. Now I wanted to add the column in existing table without deleting past records which is present in that table before running the application.
But the problem is that whenever I run the application by adding `ebean.mysqldatabase.ddl.run=true` to the ebean.properites file to add the column in existing table the past records are deleting automatically.

How to add the column in existing table without deleting records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ebean.ddl.generate=true ->  execute CREATE ALL and DROP ALL DDL scripts which create all the tables

When DDL is generated **db-create-all.sql** and **db-drop-all.sql** are generated and put into the maven target or gradle build directory. see [DDL generate](https://ebean.io/docs/ddl-generation/)

you can execute **ebean.ddl.generate=true** only to generate your Tables , After that, set the properite as **false** -> **ebean.ddl.generate=false**